# Why are numpy arrays of zero length useful?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

For example:

```
x = np.array([[[1],[2],[3]], [[4],[5],[6]]])
c = x[1:1,:,:]
print(c.shape)
print(c + 3)
```

which gives

```
(0, 3, 1)
[]
```

It seems that an array of zero length is a black hole, which absorbs all things that are added to it.

Comment: It's just a boundary case so that everything works generally. It's useful when the array represents a multi-dimensional space of data and one of the dimensions happens to be empty.

Comment: It is exactly the same answer as "why are empty strings useful" or "why is the empty list useful" or even "why is the number zero useful" — they are all [neutral elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element) with respect to some operation.

Comment: An array of zero length seems like a black hole, which absorbs all things that are added to it. In this sense, it is not an identity element.

Comment: `add` in what sense? Your addition there is "add to every element in that array", which of cause does nothing. But `add` in the `concatenate to the array`, similar to Python's list addition, then it is the identity element. It's similar to saying `0` is a blackhole wrt (number) multiplication, but is the identity wrt  (number) addition.

Comment: Look more closely at the result of `c + 3` (e.g. try `x = c + 3; print(x.shape, x.dtype)`).  You'll see that it is also an array with shape `(0, 3, 1)`.  The evaluation of that expression follows the standard rules of [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

Comment: It seems that broadcasting rules do not specify how to treat a dimension of zero size.

Comment: What do you mean, black hole? An empty array is an identity element with respect to `np.concatenate`. Just like `3 - 3` produces `0`, and `0 + 3` is `3`, in the same way `[1, 2][0:0]` is `[]` and `[] + [1, 2]` is `[1, 2]` — it is the same with numpy arrays: `np.concatenate((x, c))` is equal to `x`.